# Poor OCR prediction on real data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, ocr, attention-model

I am trying to train an OCR that detects license plates. I have used the following [repo](https://github.com/emedvedev/attention-ocr), which is an attention based OCR. So far, I managed to train on a subset of the [Synth90k](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/text/)
data set and a some other artificially generated data that include spaces as well, making a total of about 4.6 million images.

To get an idea of what the data looks like, this is an image from the Synth90k dataset: [image]

and this is one I generated artificially: [image]

Carrying out predictions on data of the same type (test data ~10% of whole data set), produces fairly satisfactory results of nearly 100% probability for each word in the test set. Exceptions occur for cases where 0 is predicted as O, 6 as G, 1 as I and vice versa etc.

Now, my problem occurs when I introduced the real data set of license plates( ~2.5k images). Due to lack of data, I thought I should probably fine tune the OCR from the last checkpoint where I used the Synth90k data and the artificial one, with the real data set. Here are some examples from the real one: [image], [image], [image].

Finally, testing my model on this data, produces very bad predictions (<70 % probablity per word in test), although the loss in training phase goes below 0.001. Is my methodology bad and if so what could be the alternatives?

Any input or guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The model learns what you teach it, and the artificial data looks *nothing* like the real one. As you said, even the test data was artificial. If you have 2500 images, use *them* to train and (most importantly) test the model

Comment: `results of nearly 100% probability` that's a clear failure indicator. No model has 100% success rate unless it was trained on the test data already - or if the test data is a slight variation of the train data.

Comment: Synth90k consists of real English words. Compared to that, license plates are random strings. A model trained on the dataset will probably generate strings that are similar to the plate number and look like English words.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "that's a clear failure indicator". Not necessarily. OCR is reasonably easy task, we have 0.2 % character error rate on some very real unseen data (printed German pre 1900).

Comment: `printed German pre 1900` is completely different from real-life photos taken at random angles, lighting conditions,contrast or focus. FineReader *personal* offered almost 100% rates for printed text back in the late 1990s. They'd done a lot of training and testing with real data to get to that point though